# codeigniter get value from form

Tags: codeigniter

I am a beginner codeigniter. 
My purpose is get value from form of example_view.php view, then display this result in the result.php view, when i submitted.

1. how can i correct this problem?
2. If i want to pass this value into session, how can i do?

**example_view.php(view)**

```
<html>
<head><title>Test Example View</title></head>

<body>
<h1 align="center">Test Sample CI Framwork</h1>

<?php echo form_open('example/getvalue'); ?>
<input type="text" name="username" value="" size="50" />
<div><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit"/></div>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

**result.php(view)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php echo 'Your new value is '.$value;?>
</body>
</html>
```

**example.php(controller)**

```
<?php
class Example extends Controller {

 function Example()
 {
  parent::Controller(); 
   $this->load->helper('form');
   $this->load->helper('url');

 }

 function index() {
  $this->load->view('example_view');
  $this->getvalue();
 }

 function getvalue()
{
 if ($this->input->post('submit')==true) {
 $data['value']=$this->input->post('username');
  $this->load->view('result',$data);
 }

}

}
?>
```

Thank for your help.

Answer (score 10):

If you are using form_validation too, you can use

```
set_value('test'); // $_POST['test']
```

Otherwise use

```
$this->input->post('test'); // $_POST['test']
```

In your form, set something like;

```
$data = array('name' => 'field' => 'value' => $this->input->post('test'));
echo form_input($data);
```

Comment: I have replaced like tihs: <html>
<head><title>Test Example View</title></head>
<body>
<h1 align="center">Test Sample CI Framwork</h1>

<?php echo form_open('example/getvalue'); ?>
<?php 
$data = array('name' => 'username','value' => $this->input->post('username'));

echo form_input($data);
?>
<div>
<?php echo form_submit(array('name'=>'submit'), 'Submit!');?></div>

<?php echo form_close(); ?>
</body>
</html>

Answer (score 4):

To get the value in codeigniter from input you can use `post`

```
$this->input->post('name');
```

You can also get the value from a GET method

```
$this->input->get('name');
```

Answer (score 0):

I've copied and pasted your code, and everything seems to be working fine for me - I'm a little unclear as to what your problem under "1." is?

As for sessions, the CodeIgniter guide is pretty useful for this: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html

Essentially, you need to load the session library first with

```
$this->load->library('session');
```

Then you can set session data with

```
$this->session->set_userdata('some_name','some_value');
```

So your final function would look something like this

```
function getvalue()
{
 if ($this->input->post('submit')==true) {
 $data['value']=$this->input->post('username');
 $this->session->('username',$data['value']);
 $this->load->view('result',$data);
 }
}
```

You can then retrieve the data by calling $this->session->userdata('item'), so for your code

```
echo $this->session->userdata('username');
```

should output whatever has been put into the textbox (but don't forget to run some security checks on the input box first!)